# Dynamically change Tab UIID not working properly in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I am using tab in one of the form.

if any error occurred while saving the form then tab color should change.

Code i have used as below:

```
for(Integer tabIndex: errorTabIndex){
if(index==0){
    tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
}
Button c = (Button) tabs.getTabsContainer().getComponentAt(tabIndex);
c.setUIID("Tab_button_error");
c.repaint();
index++;
}
```

This code set the new UIID but when i click on tab then instead of stick on new UIID style, it reset previous UIID style.

Comment: Added the java tag for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab buttons used to have two separate styles for selected and unselected. This was later consolidated so the tabs behave as a single toggle button (radio button) however one thing that remained is a call to `setUIID` that is implicitly made to restore the original "Tab" style. So effectively we invoke the `setUIID` call on the Tab.

After adding all the tabs just invoke `setTabUIID(null)` to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are not Buttons but RadioButtons.

Your uiid **Tab_button_error** should have selected style you want to show, if the tab it's going to be applied to is selected, otherwise style the Unselected.

The `repaint()` or `revalidate()` method should be called on the tabs container and not the RadioButtons.

Use component inspector to check what state your tab RadioButtons are and what UIID they carry.

```
for(Integer tabIndex: errorTabIndex) {
    if(index==0) {
        tabs.setSelectedIndex(tabIndex);
    }
    RadioButton radTab = (RadioButton) tabs.getTabsContainer().getComponentAt(tabIndex);
    radTab.setUIID("Tab_button_error");
    tabs.getTabsContainer().repaint();
    index++;
}
```